# Oddo, Can't access fields declared in _inherited child class

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I have a model `todo.task` in module `todo` as follows

```
class TodoTask(models.Model):
    _name='todo.task'
    name=fields.Char('Description',required=1)
    is_done=fields.Boolean('Done?')
    active1=fields.Boolean('Active?',default=True)
```

I have another module named `todo_user` which depends on module `todo` 
 `'depends': ['base','todo','mail'],`

in this second module I wanted to add a new field `date_deadline` to `todo.task` with the help of *Odoo's inheritance*. This is how I did that(in module `todo_user`)

```
class TodoTask(models.Model):
    _inherit=['todo.task','mail.thread']
    date_deadline=fields.Date('Deadline')
```

**I can't access the field `date_deadline` from xml in `todo` module**

Answer (score 1):

_name must be same as _inherit, fix you code like this:

```
class TodoTask(models.Model):
    _name = 'todo.task'
    _inherit = 'todo.task'
```

Comment: But I have to also inherit from `mail.thread` . I have included the `_name = 'todo.task'` line but xml in `todo` module can't access the `date_deadline` field. Shows following error while upgrading `todo` module *Field `date_deadline` does not exist*

Comment: in odoo we have 3 type of inheritance. one: _inherit = 'model'; second: _name = 'model', _inherit='model' and third _inherits = 'model'. you can inhrit mail.thread too it,s no problem, just learn how to inherit properly, read documentation

follow this [link](https://www.odoo.com/forum/how-to/developers-13/whats-the-difference-between-inherit-and-inherits-52205) for more documentation

Comment: Ok so in my case I have to add a field where the second type inheritance that you specified is best suit. How can i also inherit from `mail.thread`